# PureLayout on device: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

today I found out that there is an issue with my project. I can't run it on a real device, because I am getting an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error when it reaches the part of code that comes from a pod that I am using. I can run the app if I comment the part with this code.
The problem here is that I did not encounter this problem before and it just came out of nothing.

Under linked frameworks and libraries, my pod is linked as 'optional', because I get 'dyld: Library not loaded' error if it is marked as 'required'. Bitcode is enabled as well, changing this didn't make any difference.

Currently I am using XCode 7.0 (7A220) and Cocoapods version 0.38.2.

I'd be glad for any given tips on this.

@Edit
I've found out, that I was able to run other pods. The issue comes with PureLayout pod.

@Edit2 Code

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  var label : UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.setupView()
  }

  func setupView() {
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

      label = UILabel()
      self.view.addSubview(label)
      label.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
  }
}
```

This view controller is displayed when app is launching. This code represents the whole situation as app crashes even on this simple view -
`[UILabel autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Edit
Same code works on release build config. Does anyone know why?

Comment: When I run the same code on release build configuration it doesn't crash. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What does 'Same code' mean. Does it not crash anymore?

Comment: 'Same code' means the one that I've posted. When I run it on release build it doesn't crash. It still crashes on debug build configuration. Can't understand why.

Comment: I am really confused. I kept on looking for the answer for all this things. I kept restoring the git repository after making too many changes in project. It keeps on working and failing. Sometimes it works on debug, and it fails on release, but there is no strict condition for this. It just starts working and then after restoring once more it keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can suggest is start all over from the vary beginning. Depending on how much code you have this might be intimidating, but it is the best I have to offer. But my advice is this: don't move onto something else until the bug is obliterated, doing so can save you a lot of stress.